# Show disabled products in rss feed

Tags: magento-1.6, rss

is there any way to show disabled products in category rss feed also?

Magento 1.6.1.0

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]**
After some investigations I found out that is not possible. Not in a decent period of time at least.
The table `catalog_category_product_index` is joined with the product collection in order to get the products associated to that category. And in that index table the disabled products do not appear.

So in order to get your disabled products also you will need to rewrite the whole `_toHtml` method in the `Mage_Rss_Block_Catalog_Category` block and avoid using `addCategoryFilter`.

**[Original Post]**
I don't know why would you need that. If you show disabled products in RSS then the link in the feed will point to a 404 page.
But anyway...here is how you can do it.
You need to rewrite the `Mage_Rss_Block_Catalog_Category::_toHtml` method.
Here is what you need to change.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

needs to become

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

because if you have the flat catalog enabled, the disabled products are not indexed in the flat tables so you won't be able to access them. This way you use directly the EAV tables.

Then you need to replace

```
$layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);
```

with

```
$productCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add some attributes to select
        ->addMinimalPrice() //add all kind of prices to select
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite($currentCategory->getId());

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only visible products.
```

This is needed because the `prepareProductCollection` method filters out the disabled products. The code I suggested is basically the same thing as in `prepareProductCollection` but I removed the status filter.

Comment: Hi Marius,
thank you for your quick response!

I copied the PHP-File to local and changed the file as you said. Sadly there are still only the enabled products.

Comment: Ok. I will try to come up with something better. But keep in mind that only 50 products are shown in the RSS feed sorted by the last update time. Maybe your last 50 updated products are all enabled. Try to disable one. any product, because then it should be moved to the top of the list.

Comment: Yes, I saw the comment in the method. But there are only 3 products in the tested category. 2 enabled, 1 disabled and the RSS feed only shows 2 enabled products.

Comment: @Sebastian. See my update. Bad news.